# Put a space in the Html.labelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MiddleName)
    </div>
```

The problem i'm running into is that the label is showing as "MiddleName" how would i write it so it shows as "Middle Name"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiddleName,"Middle Name")
```

Comment: @TheDizzle While this does work, you may find it better to specify it in the model once especially if you have several controls referring to the same field.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) on your Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
public string MiddleName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I get an error that says "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @TheDizzle You get an error because this attribute takes named parameters, so you need to use `[Display(Name = "Middle Name")]`. Check my answer for full details.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best solution, but you can specify the label text explicitly by using a different `LabelFor()` overload:

```
@Html.LabelFor(
    m => m.MiddleName, "Middle Name", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely add it directly to the label itself like the accepted answer suggested:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiddleName, "Middle Name")
```

However, if you have several controls referring to the same text, you will find yourself repeating the same code, for instance if you also display the field name in the validation message. In this case, you may find it much easier and more elegant to add it to the model instead:

```
[Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
public string MiddleName { get; set; }
```